# Why is Google Group exporting members not giving me an accurate number?

Tags: google-groups

I used this script to export the email addresses from my group, and that gets me 8815 results. But on my group's page, the total number of members is 13,000+ (according to the counter in the top right corner, in member view). Why is there a difference?

```js
function listGroupMembers() {
     var GROUP_EMAIL = "mygroupsname@googlegroups.com";
     var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
     var users = group.getUsers();
     var s = "Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + users.length +
     " members: ";
     for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
       var user = users[i];
       s = s + user.getEmail() + ", ";
     }
     var doc = DocumentApp.create('group emails');
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph(s);
   }
```